# how to multiply combobox selected index value to label value

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

how to multiply combobox selected index value to label value this is easy question i know but i could not arrange to  get solution ton of hours please help me.

tried :

```
label17.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString())) *(Convert.ToInt32(label16.Text).ToString());
```

Comment: Do you want to multiply (a * b)? Where a is the combo box selected index and b is the text property of the label16?

Comment: yes i want to multiply (combobox.selectedindex(value) to label16(value))   both values are integers

Answer (score 0):

```
label17.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex * Convert.ToInt32(label16.Text)).ToString();
```

When you write some code and it doesn't work take a look at it and ask yourself a question. What is this I've written? What will happen when this line executes etc. If it is too complex to answer - break it into smaller parts and you'll see where is the problem.

Comment: ty for helping. unfortunately it has same result as mine: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: This means that your label16.Text value is not a string representation of an integer number or maybe not in the format that you expect it to be. Try setting the label to "123" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```
label17.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()) +(Convert.ToInt32(label16.Text)))).ToString();
```

**Edit** : try this,

```
int temp;
if (int.TryParse(label16.Text, out temp))
{
    label17.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex * Convert.ToInt16(label16.Text)).ToString();
}
else { MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number);}
```

Comment: ty for helping. unfortunately it has same result as mine: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: and i want to * not + haha ty in advance

Comment: it was the short version. But you have to use Int.Parse to be sure you get a correct number.  `int temp;
if (int.TryParse(label16.Text, out temp))
{
    // It's an integer
}`

Comment: thank you kaj i tried update version and it showed me messagebox  i am not guessing why ut doesnt work because allnumbers are integers.

Comment: Would you please double check your names ? Because if you pass an integers to the same method, it'll work, so I suspect there is a mistake in some name of your labels ! try it out https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmPCMf

Comment: By the way : be aware, selectedIndex is starting from 0 not from 1. So if you choose the first element in your comboBox, it's 0 not 1

Comment: ohhh i guess this doesnt work beacuse all those data i have imported from database ths reason yes?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you get the data from. Just when select an item, it's index is always -1 from the regular count. so you start count from 0 not from 1. So if you want the real value of the selected value, you have to add +1 to the method which will get the value seen in the comboBox

Comment: yes but after that i change combobox to textbox but ir didnt work too. but it works when i dont use data from database integers. i have ne question when i import some information from database is it im[orted as real variable?

Comment: It'll read it as it's in the textBox, so if you have a textBox, so what in it is a string. It doesn't matter where from you get the text. It's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
label17.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex * (Convert.ToInt32(label16.Text))).ToString();
```